# Mysql matchmaking / pairing

Tags: join, mysqli, group-by, matchmaking

I'm currently working on a 1v1 online game and I ran into a problem when trying to match up players.

A player who wants to play gets put into a matchmaking table

id, user, amount

Now I want to query the table matchmaking for the best possible pairs of users (So, users who want to play for the same amount)
I also want users who are waiting for a longer time (smaller id), to be paired up first.

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM matchmaking a, wpr_matchmaking b
WHERE a.user != b.user
AND a.amount = b.amount
ORDER BY a.id ASC , b.id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This returns all possible pairings, so in a table with this content:

```
id, user, amount
1, 1, 10
2, 2, 10
3, 3, 10
```

I get the pairs:

```
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,3
3,1
3,2
```

Whereas I only want 1,2 returned in that case.

How do I make it only show me each user at most once?

Edit: adding the condition '**and a.id < b.id**' to the query reduces the pairings by a factor of 2, but there's still too many.

Answer (score -1):

Do you just want the highest pair to match those and then rerun the query? You could use `SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: Sadly I need all matches, not just one.  If there's 4 users in the table: 1,2,3,4, all playing for the same amount, i want to get "1,2" and "3,4" returned